# SQL query does not stop executing

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've created a stored procedure that selects from a few different tables in different dbs into temp tables to work with in the proc. Everything seems to be fine with filling the tables. My problem arises when I attempt to join them. This is the query I wrote:

```
SELECT #temp1.id,
    #temp2.first_name,
    #temp2.last_name,
    #temp3.DOB,
    #temp4.Sex, 
    #temp5.SSN
FROM (((#temp1
LEFT JOIN #temp3 ON #temp1.id = #temp3.id) 
LEFT JOIN #temp4 ON #temp1.id = #temp4.id)
LEFT JOIN #temp2 ON #temp1.id = #temp2.id)
LEFT JOIN #temp5 ON #temp1.id = #temp5.id;
```

The query works to an extent. The output window is filled with the results of the select. The problem is that the query doesn't exit. It stops adding new records to the output but continues executing and thus the procedure hangs because it can't move on to the next statement. Any ideas?

Comment: Try running one join at a time and determine if one particular join is causing it to hang.  Can you verify that all records that should be returned are returned when it appears to 'hang'?  How many records in each table?  Is ID unique on all tables?  If there are duplicates the number of records returned could be very large.  With answers to these questions it may be easier for folks here to help you out.  Column names and types would be helpful as well.

Comment: What do you mean the query doesn't exit? If the query is not completing that is likely an indication that something is wrong in the query.

Comment: Did you look at the actual execution plan? Another thing you could try is recompile stored proc. Sometimes if database undergoes significant changes to its data or structure, recompiling a procedure updates and optimizes the procedure’s query plan for those changes. This can improve the procedure’s processing performance.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that your query is resulting in high table scan for all the 5 tables in the execution plan. You can create indexes on the joining column (ID) in all the 5 temp tables as follows:

```
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_t1_ID ON #temp1(ID)
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_t2_ID ON #temp2(ID)
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_t3_ID ON #temp3(ID)
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_t4_ID ON #temp4(ID)
 CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_C_t5_ID ON #temp5(ID)
```

It'd be really helpful if you can include number of rows and columns for all the 5 tables.

Answer (score 0):

How many records are in #temp1?  Are you seeing that same number of records in your output window?  If not, then your query is still returning records.

Also, did you explicitly begin a transaction somewhere in your script?  Maybe it is waiting for you to commit or rollback.

Also, I'm not sure why you have parenthesis around your joins.  They aren't needed (and maybe you are getting some weird execution plan by using them).

Answer (score 0):

The running time of this query depends (among else) on the **Number of rows** in #temp1 and on the **indexes** that it has (by default --> nothing ).

First step would be as I see it:
**Isolating the execution plan, specifically for this query.** You can do so, by filling your data into `temp1` (and not `#temp1`),

Then - **try running only the query against** `temp1`.

Seeing the execution plan for the query, may recommend which indexes might help, and will be a first step towards optimizing it.